# Express Session Object is changing so unable to store original URL

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, backend, web-development-server

I am writing an express app and it has a login functionality when someone tries to perform certain action.
So it automatically redirects you to login page if you are not logged in which is done by writing a custom middleware.
But in the middleware I am able to store the original url in session but when I try to access in post handler the session object doesnot have my "returnTo" there[here is the console logs which might help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptDtA.png)

**MIDDLEWARE THAT I DEFINED**

```
module.exports.isLoggedIn = (req,res,next)=>{
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()){
        // console.log(req.originalUrl);
        req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;
        console.log('middleware', req.session);
        req.flash('error', 'You must be signed in!')
        return res.redirect('/login')
    }
    next();
}
```

**ROUTES TO ALWAYS /campgrounds as redirectUrl is always empty**

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {failureFlash: true, failureRedirect: '/login'}) ,(req,res)=>{
    req.flash('success', 'Welcome Back!');
    console.log('router post :', req.session)
    const redirectUrl = req.session.returnTo || '/campgrounds';
    console.log(redirectUrl);
    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
})
```